# Facebook Share & Tweeter post issue with URL

Tags: php, facebook, twitter

I have following PHP function which gets current URL:

```
function getCurrentUrl() {
  $isHTTPS = ( isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"] ) && $_SERVER["HTTPS"]  ==  "on" );
  $port = ( isset($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] ) && (( !$isHTTPS && $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80" ) || ( $isHTTPS && $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "443" )));
  $port = ($port) ? ':'.$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] : '';
  $url = ( $isHTTPS ? 'https://' : 'http://').$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$port.$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
  return $url;
 }
```

Next I have following code:

```
<ul>
  <li id="face"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php echo getCurrentUrl(); ?>&t=<?php echo $title; ?>" class="popup" title="Facebook">Share</a></li>
  <li id="tweet"><a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=<?php echo getCurrentUrl(); ?>" class="popup" title="Tweeter">Tweet</a></li>
</ul>
```

If I echo URL with `<?php echo getCurrentUrl(); ?>` proper result is returned: `http://mydomain.com/index.php?menu=13&page=7`

But when I am trying to share current URL to Facebook or Twitter, `page` is cut off, so that shared URL always looks like `http://mydomain.com/index.php?menu=13`

How can I deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) your url ?

```
function getCurrentUrl()
{
  $isHTTPS = ( isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"] ) && $_SERVER["HTTPS"]  ==  "on" );
  $port = ( isset($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] ) && (( !$isHTTPS && $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80" ) || ( $isHTTPS && $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "443" )));
  $port = ($port) ? ':'.$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] : '';
  $url = ( $isHTTPS ? 'https://' : 'http://').$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$port.$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

  return urlencode($url);
}
```

Comment: I much appreciate your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that in the facebook share button you have "&t=" after the url and that might get the url wrong and cut off because &page= can be confusing for it. So i say you try to do it like this:

```
<ul>
 <li id="face"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?t=<?php echo $title; ?>&u=<?php echo getCurrentUrl(); ?>" class="popup" title="Facebook">Share</a></li>
 <li id="tweet"><a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=<?php echo getCurrentUrl(); ?>" class="popup" title="Tweeter">Tweet</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm not sure about twitter that should work.

Comment: The problem here is that `&page=` goes to the `sharer.php` and not to the given url. That's why he needs to escape his url using `urlencode`.

Comment: @j0k yes i agree but i believe it works the way i said it too.    urlencode seems to solve this without changeing the place of the parameters.